# Deduce if path is adiabatic from the state space

Tags: thermodynamics, adiabatic

Can we deduce, for quasistatic processes, if a process is adiabatic by purely looking at its path in state space?

Take, for example, the process of stirring a liquid to heat it up (adiabatic) and exposing it to a hot reservoir (non-adiabatic). Both have the same path in state space.

Is it then the case that a process is more than just its path in state space? Must there be more information than its path to determine its properties?

Edit: I mean they have the same path in state space as in let's say you had a T-V diagram for the container. Both the adiabatic and non-adiabatic processes described above would look the *exact* same in the state space supposedly i.e. constant volume and increase in T so a vertical line assuming T is the y-axis.

Comment: if $U=U(S, x_1, x_2, x_3,..x_n)$ and the quasistatic path is such that $dU = y_1dx_1+y_dx_2+...$ then it is adiabatic.

Comment: This assumes all adiabats are isentropes i.e. reversible. This is not true for irreversible adiabats i.e. process like stirring

Comment: All processes are adiabatic for which $dU=\delta W$, reversible, irreversible, whatever.

Comment: @AakashLakshmanan Please be specific on what you mean by a "path in state space"

Comment: As in you can plot the process on the state space as a continuous curve

Comment: @BobD I added an edit if that helps

Comment: @AakashLakshmanan That helps, but now I'm really confused when you say "Both the adiabatic and non-adiabatic processes..". Don't you mean "both the reversible adiabatic and non-reversible adiabatic processes"?

Comment: No. The stirring is an irreversible adiabatic process while the heating from the reservoir is not adiabatic at all

Comment: @AakashLakshmanan I'm sorry, it's probably my fault, but I can't follow you. So I'm signing off and wish you luck!

Comment: They dont have the same paths, where did you get that from? It would also be useful if you specified which thermodynamic variables are changing and which arent